# Is there a way to use dapply to do pattern matching and replacement across multiple columns of a SparkR DataFrame?

Tags: sparkr

Running Spark 2.0 locally

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("$0.00 ", "$601.19 ", "$601.19 ", "$238.58 "),
             b = c("$148.81 ", "$396.85", "$24.37 ", "$24.37 "),
             c = c("$238.58 ", "$211.15 ", "$422.30 ", "$150.30")
             )

ddf <- as.DataFrame(df)
```

I'm looking to run something like this

```
ddf2 <- dapply(ddf, function(x) { regexp_replace(x, "\\$|,", "")}, schema(ddf))
```

but it returns the error

```
head(ddf2)
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 13)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: R computation failed with
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘regexp_replace’ for signature ‘"data.frame", "character", "character"’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dapply`:

```
ddf2 <- dapply(ddf, function(x) { as.data.frame(apply(x, MARGIN=2, function(y) gsub("\\$|,", "", y, perl=TRUE)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) } , schema(ddf))
```

`dapply` expects a R data.frame as output of the anonymous function.

The `regexp_replace` method expects a SparkDataFrame `Column` as input.

Example without `dapply` (only replaces the values of the `a` column):

```
withColumn(ddf,'a', regexp_replace(ddf$a, "\\$|,", ""))
```